# How to show value which is between angle Brackets (<>) on Classic ASP UI

Tags: asp-classic

I have written below code in classic asp application showing a value on UI which gets returned from the database. Data that is returned from DB is TEST which is between angle brackets(<>).

```
<tr>
    <td class='left'><%=rs_Result("Column_1")%></td>
</tr>
```

Here the value of Column_1 is TEST which is between angle brackets(<>).

In ASP UI page I am not able to see value as TEST which is between angle brackets(<>) and getting blank value instead on UI. When the value is simply  TEST then I can see the value as TEST on my UI page.

I want to handle the condition in classic ASP UI to show all the values which are between angle Brackets(<>).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Server.HTMLEncode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347(v=vs.90).aspx) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blank value has nothing to do with Classic ASP, if you specify angle brackets in a HTML page it will always be treated as a HTML tag. To avoid this you have various options;

1. Manually encode the values `<` as `&lt;` and `>` as `&gt;`
2. Use `Replace()` to to replace `<` and `>` with the HTML entity encoded values.

   ```vb
   <%= Replace(Replace(rs_Result("Column_1"), ">", "&gt;"), "<", "&lt;") %>
   ```
3. Let Classic ASP do it for you with `Server.HTMLEncode()`.

   ```vb
   <%= Server.HTMLEncode(rs_Result("Column_1")) %>
   ```

   as [@SearchAndResQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1682881/searchandresq) has [already suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168929/how-to-show-value-which-is-between-angle-brackets-on-classic-asp-ui#comment67605904_40168929).

Personally I'd go with option 3 everytime as it not only fixes angle brackets but other characters that also need to be HTML encoded to display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td class='left'><%=Server.HTMLEncode(rs_Result("Column_1"))%></td>
</tr>
```